# How do I remove directories that begin with a dot after my server was infected?

Tags: security

My server had been infected and the attacker spread a bunch of `.5randomletters` folders around my file system, with malicious code inside of them. I want to search for all the folders that begin with a dot, review them and then remove them.

How can I do that?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Both "find / -type d -name '.?????'" and "find /a/path -type d -iname ".*"" worked pretty well, but I decided to take Briam's advice and **nuke it from orbit** :) I'm putting these commands on my cheat sheet though!

Answer (score 21):

> My server had been **infected** and the attacker spread (...) **malicious code** (...).

## NUKE IT FROM ORBIT!

That's the only way to be sure that everything is secure again. If you want you could make an image an analyze how the attacker got in the system but for that system the only salvation is **reinstall from scratch**. No removing only the "dot files" will make yourself secure that your system is oke

Comment: Does the OP have a Death Star handily available? ;-) I think the original quote was to *'...Take off and Nuke the entire site from Orbit - its the only way to be sure...'* - from Aliens (the film).

Comment: @wilf [you obviouly don't know the meme](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/a/1118/27973).

Answer (score 7):

Use `find` to find all directories beginning with "." and followed by 5 characters:

```
find / -type d -name '.?????'
```

Note that your best option is probably restoring from backup and patching the hole they used to get in. Cleaning up a system can be nearly impossible, if the attacker is halfway competent. You should probably bring in an external copy of the `find` utility, in case it has been backdoored to hide these directories.

Comment: +1 nuke it from orbit, it's the only way to be sure

Answer (score 4):

Before you "nuke it from orbit", I think *you should find the leak first*, so you can prevent incidents like this from happening again. So:

1. Take the server offline
2. Boot from a rescue disk
3. Mount the infected disk
4. Analyze, find the leak
5. Clean install + harden + restore (data only) from backups

You should never boot the broken system again, only analyze it offline, just the disk data, from another system, and never run any executables on it.

Answer (score 3):

Use find:

```
find /a/path -type d -iname ".*"
```

where `/a/path` is the path into which you would like to search for the directories. In your case it would probably be `/`, `-type d` means search only for directories, `-iname ".*"` means with name starting with a `.`.